# FCC rule stating emission type for various bands

Tags: united-states, license, fcc

The general question is as follows:
Where within the FCC rules exactly (47 CFR 97.xxx or similar) does it specify the emissions type (ie. CW, Data, RTTY, Phone, etc...) allowed for a specific band for a give license class (ie. technician, General, etc..)?

For discussion and for explicit example:
Where is the US Amateur Technician 80m (3.525 to 3.6 MHz) emission types allowed specified?

*I can find many references that ultimately lead back to the ARRL "US Amateur Radio Technician Privileges" graphic showing "CW only". I cannot find within the FCC rules where it specifies the type of emission allowed for technician within this band.*

*If emissions type for a band is not specified in the FCC rules for a given license. What FCC rule dictates how this is choose otherwise?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Part 97](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-97) [subpart D](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-97/subpart-D?toc=1) lists everything, but it is fairly lengthy, so here's the specific sections...

- 97.301 (a) Authorized Frequency bands for technician (vhf and higher)
- 97.301 (e) Authorized Frequency bands for novice and technician (HF)
- 97.305 (c) Authorized emission types
- 97.307 (f) Emissions standards / limitations: notes linked to 97.305(c)

Note that the sections above list frequency ranges by license types and frequency ranges by emission types separately.  So for instance, the sections of the HF band authorized for technicians are separately listed as only allowing RTTY and data emissions for all license types.   The emission types table then links to  97.307(f)notes (9) for pieces of 80m, 40m, 15m and (10) for 10m.  97.307(f)(9) specifically says novice and technician "may only transmit a CW emission using the international Morse code" (for the associated HF bands) and note (10) adds to that on pieces of 10m "phone emissions J3E and R3E"

The introduction to 97.305 specifically states CW can be used on any authorized frequency.  There are multiple references to emissions types scattered through subpart D.  The first paragraph mentions CW.  The tables specifically list RTTY, phone, data, image, test.
If you are concerned about something not specifically one of these types, you will need to read through the whole section to see if it is mentioned or covered by something else that is mentioned.  Note that with the exception of CW and RTTY, the emission type is largely classified by content type, and method of encoding is a secondary consideration, although content type tends to imply a bandwidth as well.

The information in part D is badly scattered, it's hard to find everything relevant without a very careful read through.

Comment: 47 CFR 97.305, the table shows (3) HF (i) 80m frequencies: entire band, emissions type authorized as RTTY, data but is subject to 97.307 paragraphs (f)(3),(9).

47 CFR 97.307 paragraph (9): A station having a control operator holding a Novice or Technician Class operator license may only transmit a CW emission using the international Morse code.

Comment: Thanks, missed that.  It's such a huge section.